# Animating 3d objects with Sceneform

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I have been searching for animating 3D objects via Sceneform. I am very new to AR.

Can anybody provide a sample for 3D animation like a moving human?

Comment: You can find an example of programmatic animation in the Sceneform Solar System sample - https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/solarsystem/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/solarsystem/RotatingNode.java

Answer (score 4):

Sceneform does not support animated renderables (like support for the animated FBX file format) right now. You can only move or rotate objects but you can't get something like a walking human easily.

Answer (score 0):

> **Sceneform SDK for Android v1.7.0 supports animation (`15th February 2019`)**.

- Sceneform includes an optional animation library, `com.google.ar.sceneform:animation` which enables animation playback.
- Added `ModelAnimator` and `AnimationData` classes. Sceneform now has the ability to play animated models.
- Added `SkeletonNode` class which can be used to bind nodes to bones in a skinned renderable, making it possible to attach objects to bones, access the positions of bones, and manipulate the positions of bones directly.
- Added `AugmentedFaceNode` to the UX library which can be used to render visuals with ARCore's `Augmented Faces` feature. See the new sample in the `/samples/augmentedfaces`/ directory.
- Added `Vector3.equals(Vector3)` and `Quaterion.equals(Quaterion)`.
- Exposed `Quaternion(Vector3 eulerAngles)` and `Quaternion.eulerAngles()` publicly.

> Sceneform lets you import models with animation. You can use Sceneform APIs to play back and control the animation, and attach nodes to a model's skeleton.
>
> For instance, the [Sceneform Animation sample](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/samples) includes files used to build models of Andy the android and a baseball hat. The Andy model contains animation data, while the baseball hat is a non-animated model. When you run the sample, Andy breakdances and waves his arms while the hat remains fixed to his head using a node.
>
> It's important to differentiate between model animation in Sceneform versus property animation in Android.
>
> Model animations are created ahead of time by artists using modeling and animation software. They contain [Skeletal Animation Data](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/animation/#model-concepts). These animations must be exported as `fbx` files, then imported into a `sfb` file (binary asset) to be used in Sceneform.
>   Property animation is a fundamental Android concept and is not specific to Sceneform. This kind of animation can change any mutable value on a Java object that has a getter and a setter. The animated values can be set dynamically, but cannot be packaged into an `sfb` file.

Hope this helps.